# C# update table not updating as intended

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table called HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE. When a user creates a new record in the table through my application, the ACTION_TYPE field is assigned the value "ADD". When a user updates a row, I want the ACTION_TYPE field to contain the value "CHANGE" if the current ACTION_TYPE value is not equal to "ADD". The issue I'm trying to resolve is that when you create a new row in my application, it should always have an ACTION_TYPE value of "ADD". However, when I update that row created via my application, it then changes to "CHANGE". I have tried fixing this with the code below, but the value still updates to "CHANGE" in this situation.

Controller

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE holiday_date_table = db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Find(id);
        if (holiday_date_table == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(holiday_date_table);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Table8/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE holiday_date_table)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var somevar = holiday_date_table.HID.ToString();
            string aconnectionString1 = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
            string checkgroup1 = "SELECT ACTION_TYPE FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE WHERE HID = @ACTION";
            using (SqlConnection _mycon = new SqlConnection(aconnectionString1))
            {
                    using (SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(checkgroup1, _mycon))
                    {
                        _mycon.Open();
                        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@ACTION", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = somevar;
                        string checkresult = (string)mycmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        //cmd31.Parameters.Add("@SECURITY_GROUP", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
                        //string checkresult = (string)mycmd.ExecuteScalar();

                        if (checkresult == "ADD")
                        {
                            db.Entry(holiday_date_table).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            holiday_date_table.ACTION_TYPE = "CHANGE";
                            db.Entry(holiday_date_table).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        return RedirectToAction("../Billing/HolidayDateTable");
        }
```

View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<br />
    @*<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HID)
    </div>
      *@
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HID)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TABLE_NUMBER)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TABLE_NUMBER)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TABLE_NUMBER)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HOLIDAY_DATE)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HOLIDAY_DATE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HOLIDAY_DATE)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FIELD_DESCRIPTION)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FIELD_DESCRIPTION)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FIELD_DESCRIPTION)
    </div>
<br />
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value=" Update " />
    </p>

 }
```

To maybe clarify things a bit. I need to prevent rows with an ACTION_TYPE value of "ADD" from being updated to "CHANGE".

**Update:** I set a breakpoint and found that somevar is getting the correct id, and checkresult had the value of "ADD " (with a space), so I changed the if statement to

```
if (checkresult == "ADD ")
```

However it still changes the value from ADD to CHANGE. I'm lost.

Comment: sounds like your `checkgroup1` query is returning something other than 'ADD'

Comment: and if you're using entity framework, why not write linq instead? something like `ctx.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLEs.Single(x => x.HID == somevar).ACTION_TYPE`?

Comment: yes, I think the problem might be var somevar = holiday_date_table.HID.ToString(); not getting the primary key value, but I don't know why.